# Excel VBA Cell will not activate

Tags: vba, excel

When I run my code it says I am using the correct cell (through my variables), but it does not activate the cell or input my variable value into the cell.

```
myColumnNumber = 1
Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1).Activate

Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1) = FirstName & LastName

myColumnNumber = myColumnNumber + 1
Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1) = AccNumber
myColumnNumber = myColumnNumber + 1
Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1) = AccName
```

My variables all show the correct values when running, but the sheet does not change.  For example, if I put Range("a1").Activate for the Active Sheet I can see when that cell activates, but my variables do not affect the change in position.

MyColumnNumner steps through adding "1" and my Current row stays at 2, as it should, but on the sheet there is no change.  Can you see any errors in this snip, or is more information required?  thank you for any assistance.

Comment: try `.Select` in your case but do not use `.Select` in general

Comment: put range.value = Name rather than just range

Comment: Your syntax is off.  Try `Cells(currentRow1, myColumnNumber).Activate`

Comment: Why do you want to activate on the first place. You could just put the value. An alternative way to put value in cell is Cells(currentRow1, myColumnNumber).Value=FirstName & LastName I prefer this over the other one.

Comment: Or the whole thing reduces to `Cells(currentRow1, myColumnNumber).resize(1,3).value = Array(FirstName & LastName
, AccNumber, AccName)`

Comment: Thanks, I will give these a try.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did not see your comment before I posted my answer.  +1 on your comment for beating me to it by 1 minute :)

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for the help!! another person added the same response below, thank YOU as well.

Comment: `.Activate`? Nooooooooooooo! :) You might want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: You cannot give an integer value to a column name in range. You should put myColumnNumber = "A" rather than 1. And to enter values to adjacent cells ,use offset. Its damn easy to use Cells instead of Range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, never use `.Activate` or `.Select` if you can avoid it.  Your code can be reproduced as a one-liner:

```
Cells(currentRow1, myColumnNumber).Resize(, 3).Value = Array(FirstName & LastName, AccNumber, AccName)
```

As a side note, you are trying to use `Range("Address")` but are giving it a number as the column, so use Cells instead of Range (as shown in my provided code).

What I mean by that is, the Range method takes column letters, like `Range("A1")` or `Range("C3")`.  You are giving it numbers, so it looks like this `Range("11")` which isn't a valid range.  I'm kind of surprised you're not getting an error.

The Cells method, however, takes column numbers or column letters. `Cells(rownumber, columnnumber)` which is how you should be referencing the appropriate cell, based on the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1) should reference the range in your workbook.

try adding a range object instead of using Range to reference.

```
dim rng as Range
set rng = Activeworksheet.Cells

myColumnNumber = 1 
rng (myColumnNumber & currentRow1).Activate
rng (myColumnNumber & currentRow1) = FirstName & LastName

myColumnNumber = myColumnNumber + 1
rng (myColumnNumber & currentRow1) = AccNumber
myColumnNumber = myColumnNumber + 1
rng (myColumnNumber & currentRow1) = AccName
```

Comment: sorry, I didnt see this, the rng before (myColumnNumber & currentRow1) = FirstName & LastName

Comment: Same result.  Only cell A1 stays highlighted and none of my values are added.

Answer (score 0):

```
myColumnNumber = "A"
Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1).Activate 'No Use

Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1).Value = FirstName & LastName

' myColumnNumber = myColumnNumber + 1   Error
'The Offset property is the one that you will use the most with Range to move around
'the 'sheet.                  

Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1).Offset(0,1).Value = AccNumber
Range(myColumnNumber & currentRow1).Offset(0,2).Value = AccName
```

Comment: This still does not work.  The correct cell is not being selected and the values are not being entered.  I looked at the MSDN as well and added the sheetname for each line and that did not work either.